# Almgren and Taylor's movie about soap bubbles

Tags: reference-request, geometric-measure-theory, minimal-surfaces, popular-math

As I know, in 1970's two well-known geometric analysts, Fred Almgren and Jean Taylor, along with mathematician Michele Emmer, produced a film about minimal surfaces entitled "Soap Bubbles". I would like to know, whether or not there is a version of this film available somewhere on the net. As it produced by the pioneers of the field, it seems very pleasant to watch.
More information about this could be find in this paper by Emmer:
[Art and Mathematics: a series of films](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/39430087_Art_and_Mathematics_a_series_of_films)